# How to properly update users count using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have searched StackOverflow but most of the solutions found could not solve my issue at the moment.

The Code below displays users records from the array via reactjs.

Now I have the task to display users count on content display.

In **Jquery/Javascript**, I can achieve it using the function below

```
function updateCount(userId){
  alert('userId: ' +userId);

  var count = (userCount[userId] == undefined) ? 1 : userCount[userId] + 1;
  userCount[userId] = count;

  alert('Counter: ' +userCount[userId]);
  console.log('Counter: ' +userCount[userId]);

  $('#' + userId + ' label.userCount').html(count);
  $('#' + userId + ' label.userCount').show();

}
```

Now in **Reactjs**, I created the following function below which I added to the main code but it throws error

**Reactjs functions**

```
updateCount = (userId) => {
  alert('userId: ' +userId);

  var count = (userCount[userId] == undefined) ? 1 : userCount[userId] + 1;
  userCount[userId] = count;

  alert('Counter: ' +userCount[userId]);
  console.log('Counter: ' +userCount[userId]);  

  this.setState(state => ({
    data: userCount[userId]
  }));
}
```

**Here is the error it shows**

```
bundle.js:109480 Uncaught ReferenceError: userCount is not defined
    at App._this.updateCount
```

**Below is the entire code so far**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            userCount: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var userId = "100";

        //var userCount = [];
        //this.userCount = [];

        this.setState({
            data: [
                {
                    id: "100",
                    name: "Luke"
                },
                {
                    id: "200",
                    name: "Henry"
                },
                {
                    id: "300",
                    name: "Mark"
                }
            ]
        });

        this.updateCount = this.updateCount.bind(this);
    }

    updateCount = userId => {
        alert("userId: " + userId);

        var count = userCount[userId] == undefined ? 1 : userCount[userId] + 1;
        userCount[userId] = count;

        alert("Counter: " + userCount[userId]);
        console.log("Counter: " + userCount[userId]);

        this.setState(state => ({
            data: userCount[userId]
        }));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                <label>
                    <ul>
                        {this.state.data.map((person, i) => {
                            if (person.id == 100) {
                                this.updateCount(person.id);

                                return (
                                    <div key={i}>
                                        <div>
                                            {" "}
                                            {person.id}: {person.name}{" "}
                                        </div>{" "}
                                    </div>
                                );
                            } else {
                                this.updateCount(person.id);
                            }
                        })}
                    </ul>{" "}
                </label>{" "}
            </span>
        );
    }
}
```

**Updated Section**
It shows error of unexpected token with the code below

[image: screenshot]

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";

    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          userCount: [],
        };
      }

     componentDidMount() {
   // componentWillMount(){
    var userId= '100';

    //var userCount = [];
    //this.userCount = [];


        this.setState({
          data: [
            { id: "100", name: "Luke"},
            { id: "200", name: "Henry"},
            { id: "300", name: "Mark" }
          ]
        });

     this.updateCount = this.updateCount.bind(this);
      }



    updateCount = (userId) => {
    //alert('userId: ' +userId);

    const {userCount} = this.state;

    var count = userCount[userId] == undefined ? 1 : userCount[userId] + 1;

      //var count = (userCount[userId] == undefined) ? 1 : userCount[userId] + 1;
      userCount[userId] = count;

    alert('Counter kk000000me: ' +userCount[userId]);
    console.log('Counter: ' +userCount[userId]);

    this.setState({data11: count});

    }

    const result = this.state.data.map((person, i) => {
        if (person.id == 100) {
            this.updateCount(person.id); //Every time this is called, it triggers setState

            return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <div>
                        {" "}
                        {person.id}: {person.name}{" "}
                    </div>{" "}
                </div>
            );
        } else {
          this.updateCount(person.id);
        }
      });


    render() {
      return (
        <span>
          <label>
            <ul> {result} </ul>
          </label>
        </span>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your state variables, you need to do it like

```
this.state.userCount
```

In your example you're trying to access your `userCount` without referring to it in the state.

`var count = userCount[userId] == undefined ? 1 : userCount[userId] + 1;`

You should instead do:

```
const {userCount} = this.state;

var count = userCount[userId] == undefined ? 1 : userCount[userId] + 1;
```

---

## Edit

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor)

To fix this issue, you have to ensure that your component is not triggering `setState` inside of itself. In your snippet, when you `map` over your data, it calls `updateCount` which then calls `this.setState()` which will trigger a re-render.

One solution would be to assign the result of your map to a const, and the render it.

```
  const result = this.state.data.map((person, i) => {
    if (person.id == 100) {
        this.updateCount(person.id); //Every time this is called, it triggers setState

        return (
            <div key={i}>
                <div>
                    {" "}
                    {person.id}: {person.name}{" "}
                </div>{" "}
            </div>
        );
    } else {
      this.updateCount(person.id);
    }
  });

  ...

render() {
  return (
    <span>
      <label>
        <ul> {result} </ul>
      </label>
    </span>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Keno, the counter now works but am having errors below in the console. Please can you help me further. Here is the error warnings on the console   bundle.js:5125 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: @NancyMooree just saw your reply. The error you're having is likely because you're calling `updateCount` inside of your `render()` which also sets state again. Every state change will result in a re-render leading to an infinite render loop. What you should instead do is perform the `map` outside of your render, store it inside a `const` and then render that variable. Does this help?

Comment: Please Sir Keno, can you provide me with coding example, I still cannot figure out how to go about with it. hoping to hear from you soonest. Between Thanks

Comment: @NancyMooree Sure, I'll edit my post with a possible solution shortly.

Comment: @NancyMooree check the edit, hopefully that is of help to you.

Comment: Sir Keno, Thanks once more. I have updated the code with your solution but it shows error of unexpected token. please can you see the Updated section of my post to see the error in the screenshots and how I implemented your solution. Hoping to hear from you soonest. Between thanks for helping me so far

Comment: @NancyMooree Remove `const` from it if you're defining it within your class component. It should work then.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I accepted your answer as solving my initial question of the Post regarding counter. Other issues I will try and see if I can work it out. Thanks